Calculate the simplest dyadic rational in half-open interval
Given a half-open interval $[a, b)$ can one calculate, without brute force or looping of any kind, the simplest dyadic rational within said range?
Context:
I'm reading about arithmetic coding which involves finding a dyadic rational within a given half-open interval. I am familiar with and already have methods to brute-force solve this.
Example:
Given this message scheme:
Alphabet of:
$$\mathcal{X} = \{ 0, 1, 2 \}.$$
Probabilities of:
$$p = (0.2, 0.4, 0.4).$$
Message of:
$${x_1, x_2, x_3} = 210.$$ i.e. 3 characters, 2, 1, and 0.
Then the half-open interval $[a, b)$ that encodes the message $210$ is $[0.68, 0.712)$. The simplest dyadic rational within this interval is $0.6875$ which has a dyadic rational representation of $0.1011$.
Is it possible to compute these solutions without brute force searching?

Does calculating the binary expansions of $a$ and $b$ count as looping?

@GregMartin do you mean calculating that $a$ and $b$ are $0.10101110000101$ and $0.101101100100011$ respectively? No

Then that leads to the simple algorithm of just finding the first bit where they differ (modulo border cases).

@GregMartin I see you posted the common bits answer but then deleted it, is there a problem with that approach?

Someone else posted that. I don't think there's a problem, one just has to formulate it carefully.

I posted it, realized that I had the fiddly boundary conditions wrong, and deleted the erroneous answer until I would have time to get it right.   You're not missing anything because Greg Martin's comment is equivalent to the part of my answer that was actually correct.

The fiddly boundary conditions are: Let $c$ be the common bits between $a$ and $b$ (both expressed in terminating form if possible). If $c = a$ then it is the answer. Otherwise let $c_1$ be $c$ with an additional $1$ bit appended. If $c_1 < b$, then it is the answer. If $c_1 = b$, continue down the bits of $a$ until the next $0$ bit is encountered. Turn this bit to $1$ and truncate all remaining bits. This will be the answer.
